# Out of order operations on AnyCubic Prusa-I3 clone

Tags: print-quality, prusa-i3

Another thing I'm seeing with my new build.
Late in a small print, the unit appears to perform operations "out of order" occasionally.  Here's a picture where it's running a layer across the model.
[image]

These "skips" can start in the middle of a line.  It always comes back and fills them in before starting the next layer - more or less accurately.  But from my very limited understanding of gcode, it doesn't seem like this should happen.

When watching the print closely, I'll occasionally see small glitches, where the head jogs very slightly as it runs a line across.

This was sliced with Cura - I'm going to try a different slicer and see if I get anything similar.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is just your slicer doing this. If you inspect the G-code file, you will see that the printer is faithfully doing what the slicer told it to. Most slicers use a fairly simple heuristic for determining the order in which lines are processed, which sometimes comes up with sub-optimal solutions like these.

Comment: It's funny to wonder what the "logic" is reading or playing when it skips peculiar shapes in a fill operation. Change one little parameter and the skipped parts are in a new location or vanish entirely, sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this in Cura 2.5 when selecting different printers, then altering the specifications to suit. Changing the printer seems to change the slicing behavior. As yet there is no specific printer set up in Cura for the MEGA so you will probably have to find something that fits your needs, unless someone has the full settings. For example, is the Machine Center at Zero? Maybe try the Prusa Mk2?